# iMac disk write issues

Tags: hard-drive, imac, macos, adobe-photoshop

I have a problem specifically with Photoshop Elements 12 Organiser and the ability to write to the internal drive on an iMac 5k with El Capitan.  I have full read write access to the files on the disk but when I try to write the metadata to the photos I get the error "An error occurred while reading files or writing files to disc.  The disc may be full or there may be a problem with the source media".
I also have other issues accessing and erasing from SD cards.

Comment: Can you write into said folder from other apps?

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you save your Photoshop file to a different directory or hard disk?

What are the file Permissions?
Select your file in the Finder and go to File > Show Info > Permissions

It sounds like your file or folder permission are messed up. Also, Repair Disk Permissions (Applications → Utilities → Disk Utility):

Comment: I think it has something to do with deleting files (Photoshop elements appears to create a new file with the metadata, deletes the old file and then renames the new file).  When I try to delete files normally, Finder asks for my password to approve the deletion.

Comment: The files are in a separate folder within Users which I have created and given myself read/write access

Answer (score 0):

I have specifically added myself as a user with read/write access. I had assumed that the 'everybody' group with read/write access would react in the same way as being named separately.

Comment: Where did you make these changes? In Finder? In Photoshop Elements 12 Organiser? Usually you don't have to modify any OS X folder permissions on your hard drive. Saving files should be working out-of-the-box.

Comment: I had set up a folder using Finder under "Users" called "Shared". I right clicked on the folder to "Get Info".  I had the custom access set as Read & Write for "system", "wheel" and "everyone".  Adding myself as an individual user to the list with Read & Write access has cured the issue.  I think the problem was that Photoshop was updating the metadata on the file by first making a duplicate file with the updated metadata, then deleting the old file and then renaming the duplicate file.  Finder was previously asking for my password to delete files.

Comment: Photoshop doesn't seem to be able to cope with needing to have a password for deleting the original file as I had multiple copies of the original file.  I am such happier in general now being able to delete without the need for a password.

Comment: I'm not sure why the system treats me differently when listed as an individual user rather than as part of the 'everyone' group but I can live with it.

Comment: It's not a disk write issue. You are experiencing file and folder permission issues.  I don't know The PS Organiser’s folder structure, somehow the Application can’t write to your subfolders.

I would rather create a new Organiser Library in /Users/yourname/Pictures/Organiser and move over your existing data. Again, you don’t have to tweak your folder permissions all the time.

Comment: I had decided to have a new folder which everyone could access to the files rather than giving the family access to my user area.  I've never been a great fan of separating files by user.